# Xcode 14 beta 4 - warnings about unused return values even when using @discardableResult

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Xcode 14 beta 4 (and perhaps earlier betas but I haven't checked) I'm seeing warnings about unused return values even though the methods are annotated with `@discardableResult`. These warnings only surface for `async` methods, and as far as I can tell, only in extensions on `UIKit` classes:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
  @discardableResult
  func discardableUIKit() async -> Int {
    42
  }

  @discardableResult
  func discardableUIKit() -> Int {
    42
  }
}

extension NSObject {
  @discardableResult
  func discardableNSObject() async -> Int {
    42
  }

  @discardableResult
  func discardableNSObject() -> Int {
    42
  }
}

extension NSNumber {
  @discardableResult
  func discardableNSNumber() async -> Int {
    42
  }

  @discardableResult
  func discardableNSNumber() -> Int {
    42
  }
}

func test() {
  UIView().discardableUIKit()
  NSNumber().discardableNSObject()
  NSNumber().discardableNSNumber()
  Task {
    await UIView().discardableUIKit() // Result of call to function returning 'Int' is unused
    await NSNumber().discardableNSObject()
    await NSNumber().discardableNSNumber()
  }
}
```

I don't see these warnings in Xcode 13. Is this a bug or something new to Xcode 14/Swift 5.7 that I'm unaware of?

## Update

As mentioned in the comments, this is a bug with Swift 5.7 that affects any type that is annotated with `@MainActor`. Presumably it will be fixed before the GM is released, but it is still present in Xcode 14 beta 5.

Comment: So you only get the warning for that one variant, the UIView extension and only the async version??? That is really weird. I don't have the beta so I can only stand amazed.

Comment: Yes, only on the async declaration, and only on the UIKit object. I did test against other UIKit classes (specifically UIAlertController) and I get it on those as well, but again, only on the async versions.

Comment: I say it's a bug, and I say file it. :)

Comment: Filed as FB10992972

Comment: Actually I would have called this a Swift bug and filed it against the language at GitHub. If I had the beta I would do it for you, but I can't. :(

Comment: Yeah... shoulda gone there first. https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/60276

Comment: Still exists after the betas